# Tell android that my layout can be resized instead of cropped

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I tell android to not crop my layout when displaying the on-screen keyboard but to instead resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `adjustResize` to your `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute on each `<activity>` definition in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) for more information.